# How to read a Flatfile in batches [Spring Batch 2.7.8 , Mysql 8]

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch, flatfilereader

I have a flat file with 3200000 rows and performance of application decreases as time progresses.
For e.g 100000 rows in 30 sec to 320000 in total time of about 4 hours.
I am using jdbc template for batch saving . Also tried async read with completable future
database used = Mysql. with 2 indexes - 1 primary key , 1 unique index

expected lower time.

Comment: That should not be the case. If you share your code, I can check with you why this is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 3.2M rows _does_ take a lot time to load.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?  How big (in GB) is the table?

Answer (score 0):

**"Replacing" a table:**  If you are really "replacing" the entire table, this is much better.

For example, are you getting a *replacement* for your table every night?  If so there is a *much* less invasive way to do such.  (Not faster, but I suspect that is not the *real* issue.)  The following keeps the `real` table "online" except for a very brief, ACID, `RENAME`.

```
    CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
    load up `new` by whatever means
    RENAME TABLE real TO old,
                 new TO real;
    DROP TABLE old;
```

**LOAD DATA INFILE** (applies for either adding or replacing)

If the "flat file" is comma- or tab-separated, then see if `LOAD DATA` can be used.  It is very fast.

**Batch loading**

- I recommend 100-1000 rows per batch.  (100K rows at a shot *may* so big as to be leading to other slowdowns.  This is especially bad if replication is involved.)
- commit after each batch.  (Or use `autocommit=ON`.)  (Saving 3.2M rows in the undo buffer is costly.)

**Other notes**

Rethink whether you really need two unique indexes (the PK is one).  That doubles some of the work of inserting each row.

Answer (score 0):

(This partially addresses the "slow down" part of the question.)

The setting for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of RAM.  (However, if RAM is less than 4GB or you have lots of RAM taken up by other apps, that percentage is too high.)

If the buffer_pool grows bigger than the available RAM, then "swapping" comes into play.  This is terrible for performance.

How big is the table?  If it has lots of big text columns, then it could be quite big.  Big implies that it might overflow the buffer_pool and "slow down" as more rows are added.

Indexing with `UUIDs` also can cause a slowdown due to overflowing the buffer_pool.  This is because of the randomness of such indexes.  More:  [*UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid)

Do you really need both unique indexes?  Here's the issue.  When inserting a row, all unique indexes are checked before moving on to the next row.

- `AUTO_INCREMENT` and not specified -- appends to 'end' of table
- `UUID` -- Jumps around 'randomly'.
- DATETIME / TIMESTAMP -- If the incoming data is roughly ordered by datetime, then an index on such will be augmented in an efficient way.
- Other index types -- perhaps somewhere in between auto_inc and uuid.